# Mac only displays "Default Audio Device" when querying mixers

Tags: java, macos, javasound

When I query all the mixers on my Macintosh (MacPro 13inch; 10.13.1), all that shows up is 6 iterations of "Default Audio Device, version Unknown Version".

I am simply wondering why this is, and how I might be able to fix it. If it matters, I am compiling the code through NetBeans 8.2

Here's the method:

```
public static void displayMixers() {
        Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo(); //save info of all mixers on system to an array
        System.out.println("Available mixers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < mixerInfo.length; i++) { //for loop that iterates over the array we just established
            System.out.println(mixerInfo[0].toString()); //print description of mixer each time
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? I see nothing in this question that should be against the terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index into `mixerInfo` is `[0]` so you are just listing the first entry 6 times, Use `[i]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mixerInfo.length; i++) { 
  System.out.println(mixerInfo[i]); 
}
```

Note that you don't need the `toString()` call as `println` will do that for you.

Assuming you are using Java 5 or later it would be better to use the 'enhanced for loop' which removes the chance of using the wrong index:

```
for (Mixer.Info info : mixerInfo) {
  System.out.println(info);
}
```

On Java 8 or later you could even use a stream:

```
Arrays.stream(mixerInfo).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```